# Is Injecting Repository dependency in Integration Testing is bad practice

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I am developing REST CURD API using Spring Boot and following TDD. I am starting with READ operation to test the READ works I have to prepopulate data in my DB. For this purpose I am using H2 DB and created my Repository and using this Repository in my Integration testing Setup step to populate the data before my GET actual data being executed. My college told me its bad practice using Repository in integration testing to create data for this GET operation test instead he suggested to call POST API endpoint in Setup step and Execute GET test also implement PUT and DELETE IT tests.

My question is

1. Is injecting actual repository for purpose of data setup in Integration test class is wrong?
2. Can we use/call and Endpoint (POST) in setup or in GET testcase before actual Test logic being executed?
3. Can we call POST endpoint in init/setup and populate the data instead using Repository and implement GET,PUT,DELETE tests using POST data? Is advisable calling direct POST endpoint in setup for purpose of testing another endpoint in Test class and using @TestOrder annotation on class level.

Case 1

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CURDTest() {
 
  @Autowired
  private TestMovieRepository testMovieRepository;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
   Movie myMovie = new Movie("test");
   testMovieRepository.save(myMovie);
}

@Test
void getMovie_whenReturnsMovie(){
  //Test logic using mockMvc;
}
}
```

Case 2:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CURDTest() {
 
  
  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
   //call POST Endpoint usin MockMvc populate data in table
}

@Test
void getMovie_whenReturnsMovie(){
  //Test logic using mockMvc;
}
}
```

Case 3:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestOrder
public class CURDTest() {
 
  
  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
   //call POST Endpoint usin MockMvc populate data in table
}

@Test
@Order(1)
void getMovie_whenReturnsMovie(){
  //Test logic using mockMvc;
}

@Test
@Order(2)
void updateMovie_whenReturnsMovie(){
  //Test logic using mockMvc;
}

}
```